# How to distinguish running java programs

Tags: java

Our server machine runs many java programes. And some of them are launched with the command "java -jar ***.jar". but sometimes I have to stop one to update the class files in it. the problem is how can i fingure out which program is the one i want to stop, or is there a tool I can use to find out the executable jar files' location.

Comment: you can run `ps -aux` to get required detail (assuming you are in unix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jps` command.

```
$ jps -v
34370 Jps -Dapplication.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home -Xms8m
34341 main -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/local/Cellar/leiningen/2.5.0/libexec/leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false -Dleiningen.original.pwd=/Users/ntalbs/js-workspace/synapeditor_mobile -Dleiningen.script=/usr/local/bin/lein
```

`jps` will display all java processes. The first column is OS pid. You can check the messages on console, then kill what you want. Perhaps you want to check [jps document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jps.html) from Oracle.

Also, you can use `ps` and `grep` command.

```
$ ps -ef | grep java
```

or

```
$ ps -aux | grep java
```